# Convert string to datetime issue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a date string in one format into another. However, I get this exception error message

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

My code is as follows:

```
string theDate = "28-Feb-13 4:00:00 PM";

DateTime tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(theDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

convertedDate = tempDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
```

I seriously have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: I think your issue is string to datetime and not the other way around as in the title

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must change

`28-Feb-13 4:00:00 PM` to `28-Feb-13 04:00:00 PM`

or

`dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt` to `dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt`

Comment: When `DateTime` says `ParseExact`, it means it.

Comment: So that was what it was all about! And here I thought that the computer is smart enough to detect that. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it after I've been staring at the code for some time

Comment: @SWeko : I should have suspected that it took the word 'Exact' seriously :D

Comment: @ixora `DateTime.Parse` is the smart one that tries to figure out what kind of date string you have, tries to help out, and often goes horribly wrong. Using `ParseExact` is telling the compiler "I know my data better than you. Work like this and do not try to second guess me".

Comment: @ixora And could you mark it as a answer. So i will get more reputation. ))

Comment: @SWeko ParseExact means that: The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

Comment: @Farhad Jabiyev : I changed the code, and no longer see the error, but it seems that `tempDate` now has the value of `28-Feb-13 4:00:00 PM` while `convertedDate` is `2013-02-28 04:00:00`. So, the value of `convertedDate` is wrong and does not follow the specified format

Comment: @ixora No, `convertedDate` is correct and follows the specified format. If you think it's wrong, that's because the format specified is wrong. See here how to define the correct format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx Or maybe you're referring to `yyyy/MM...` being output as `yyyy-MM...`?

Comment: @Nolonar Thank you for the link. It is really helpful. I had no idea that `:` and `/` are format specifiers. No wonder `convertedDate` has `-` as the date separator! It was exactly based on the regional setting on my computer. Thank you once again